# building a u-net model for multi-class semantic segmenation

Tags: keras

I'm trying to build u-net in keras for multi-class semantic segmentation. The model I have below does not learn anything. It always just predicts the background (first) class.

Is my use of the final 'softmax' layer correct? The [documentation](https://keras.io/activations/#softmax) shows a `axis` parameter, but I'm not sure how to set that or what it should be.

```
def unet(input_shape=(572, 572, 1), classes=2):

    input_image = KL.Input(shape=input_shape)

    contracting_1, pooled_1 = blocks.contracting(input_image,   filters=64, block_name="block1")
    contracting_2, pooled_2 = blocks.contracting(pooled_1,      filters=128, block_name="block2")
    contracting_3, pooled_3 = blocks.contracting(pooled_2,      filters=256, block_name="block3")
    contracting_4, pooled_4 = blocks.contracting(pooled_3,      filters=512, block_name="block4")
    contracting_5, _ = blocks.contracting(pooled_4,             filters=1024, block_name="block5")

    dropout = KL.Dropout(rate=0.5)(contracting_5)

    expanding_1 = blocks.expanding(dropout,     merge_layer=contracting_4, filters=512, block_name="block6")
    expanding_2 = blocks.expanding(expanding_1, merge_layer=contracting_3, filters=256, block_name="block7")
    expanding_3 = blocks.expanding(expanding_2, merge_layer=contracting_2, filters=128, block_name="block8")
    expanding_4 = blocks.expanding(expanding_3, merge_layer=contracting_1, filters=64, block_name="block9")

    class_output = KL.Conv2D(classes, kernel_size=(1, 1), activation='softmax', name='class_output')(expanding_4)

    model = KM.Model(inputs=[input_image], outputs=[class_output])

    return model
```

blocks:

```
def contracting(input_layer, filters, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding='same',
                block_name=""):

    conv_a = KL.Conv2D(filters, kernel_size, activation='relu', padding=padding,
                       name='{}_contracting_conv_a'.format(block_name))(input_layer)
    conv_b = KL.Conv2D(filters, kernel_size, activation='relu', padding=padding,
                       name='{}_contracting_conv_b'.format(block_name))(conv_a)
    pool = KL.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), padding=padding,
                           name='{}_contracting_pool'.format(block_name))(conv_b)

    batch_normalization = KL.BatchNormalization()(pool)

    return conv_b, batch_normalization


def expanding(input_layer, merge_layer, filters, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding='same',
              block_name=""):

    input_layer = KL.UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2))(input_layer)

    conv_up = KL.Conv2D(filters, kernel_size=(2, 2), activation='relu',
                        padding='same', name='{}_expanding_conv_up'.format(block_name))(input_layer)

    conv_up_height, conv_up_width = int(conv_up.shape[1]), int(conv_up.shape[2])
    merge_height, merge_width = int(merge_layer.shape[1]), int(merge_layer.shape[2])

    crop_top = (merge_height - conv_up_height) // 2
    crop_bottom = (merge_height - conv_up_height) - crop_top
    crop_left = (merge_width - conv_up_width) // 2
    crop_right = (merge_width - conv_up_width) - crop_left

    cropping = ((crop_top, crop_bottom), (crop_left, crop_right))
    merge_layer = KL.Cropping2D(cropping)(merge_layer)
    merged = KL.concatenate([merge_layer, conv_up])

    conv_a = KL.Conv2D(filters, kernel_size, activation='relu', padding=padding,
                       name='{}_expanding_conv_a'.format(block_name))(merged)
    conv_b = KL.Conv2D(filters, kernel_size, activation='relu', padding=padding,
                       name='{}_expanding_conv_b'.format(block_name))(conv_a)

    batch_normalization = KL.BatchNormalization()(conv_b)

    return batch_normalization
```

compile:

```
optimizer = keras.optimizers.SGD(lr=0.0001, momentum=0.9)
loss = keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy
metrics = [keras.metrics.categorical_accuracy]

model.compile(optimizer, loss, metrics)
```

Model Summary:

---

```
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_2 (InputLayer)            (None, 96, 96, 3)    0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block1_contracting_conv_a (Conv (None, 96, 96, 64)   1792        input_2[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block1_contracting_conv_b (Conv (None, 96, 96, 64)   36928       block1_contracting_conv_a[0][0]  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block1_contracting_pool (MaxPoo (None, 48, 48, 64)   0           block1_contracting_conv_b[0][0]  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_10 (BatchNo (None, 48, 48, 64)   256         block1_contracting_pool[0][0]    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block2_contracting_conv_a (Conv (None, 48, 48, 128)  73856       batch_normalization_10[0][0]     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block2_contracting_conv_b (Conv (None, 48, 48, 128)  147584      block2_contracting_conv_a[0][0]  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block2_contracting_pool (MaxPoo (None, 24, 24, 128)  0           block2_contracting_conv_b[0][0]  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_11 (BatchNo (None, 24, 24, 128)  512         block2_contracting_pool[0][0]    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block3_contracting_conv_a (Conv (None, 24, 24, 256)  295168      batch_normalization_11[0][0]     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block3_contracting_conv_b (Conv (None, 24, 24, 256)  590080      block3_contracting_conv_a[0][0]  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block3_contracting_pool (MaxPoo (None, 12, 12, 256)  0           block3_contracting_conv_b[0][0]  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_12 (BatchNo (None, 12, 12, 256)  1024        block3_contracting_pool[0][0]    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block4_contracting_conv_a (Conv (None, 12, 12, 512)  1180160     batch_normalization_12[0][0]     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block4_contracting_conv_b (Conv (None, 12, 12, 512)  2359808     block4_contracting_conv_a[0][0]  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block4_contracting_pool (MaxPoo (None, 6, 6, 512)    0           block4_contracting_conv_b[0][0]  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_13 (BatchNo (None, 6, 6, 512)    2048        block4_contracting_pool[0][0]    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block5_contracting_conv_a (Conv (None, 6, 6, 1024)   4719616     batch_normalization_13[0][0]     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block5_contracting_conv_b (Conv (None, 6, 6, 1024)   9438208     block5_contracting_conv_a[0][0]  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_2 (Dropout)             (None, 6, 6, 1024)   0           block5_contracting_conv_b[0][0]  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
up_sampling2d_5 (UpSampling2D)  (None, 12, 12, 1024) 0           dropout_2[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
cropping2d_5 (Cropping2D)       (None, 12, 12, 512)  0           block4_contracting_conv_b[0][0]  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block6_expanding_conv_up (Conv2 (None, 12, 12, 512)  2097664     up_sampling2d_5[0][0]            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_5 (Concatenate)     (None, 12, 12, 1024) 0           cropping2d_5[0][0]               
                                                                 block6_expanding_conv_up[0][0]   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block6_expanding_conv_a (Conv2D (None, 12, 12, 512)  4719104     concatenate_5[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block6_expanding_conv_b (Conv2D (None, 12, 12, 512)  2359808     block6_expanding_conv_a[0][0]    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_15 (BatchNo (None, 12, 12, 512)  2048        block6_expanding_conv_b[0][0]    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
up_sampling2d_6 (UpSampling2D)  (None, 24, 24, 512)  0           batch_normalization_15[0][0]     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
cropping2d_6 (Cropping2D)       (None, 24, 24, 256)  0           block3_contracting_conv_b[0][0]  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block7_expanding_conv_up (Conv2 (None, 24, 24, 256)  524544      up_sampling2d_6[0][0]            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_6 (Concatenate)     (None, 24, 24, 512)  0           cropping2d_6[0][0]               
                                                                 block7_expanding_conv_up[0][0]   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block7_expanding_conv_a (Conv2D (None, 24, 24, 256)  1179904     concatenate_6[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block7_expanding_conv_b (Conv2D (None, 24, 24, 256)  590080      block7_expanding_conv_a[0][0]    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_16 (BatchNo (None, 24, 24, 256)  1024        block7_expanding_conv_b[0][0]    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
up_sampling2d_7 (UpSampling2D)  (None, 48, 48, 256)  0           batch_normalization_16[0][0]     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
cropping2d_7 (Cropping2D)       (None, 48, 48, 128)  0           block2_contracting_conv_b[0][0]  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block8_expanding_conv_up (Conv2 (None, 48, 48, 128)  131200      up_sampling2d_7[0][0]            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_7 (Concatenate)     (None, 48, 48, 256)  0           cropping2d_7[0][0]               
                                                                 block8_expanding_conv_up[0][0]   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block8_expanding_conv_a (Conv2D (None, 48, 48, 128)  295040      concatenate_7[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block8_expanding_conv_b (Conv2D (None, 48, 48, 128)  147584      block8_expanding_conv_a[0][0]    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_17 (BatchNo (None, 48, 48, 128)  512         block8_expanding_conv_b[0][0]    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
up_sampling2d_8 (UpSampling2D)  (None, 96, 96, 128)  0           batch_normalization_17[0][0]     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
cropping2d_8 (Cropping2D)       (None, 96, 96, 64)   0           block1_contracting_conv_b[0][0]  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block9_expanding_conv_up (Conv2 (None, 96, 96, 64)   32832       up_sampling2d_8[0][0]            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_8 (Concatenate)     (None, 96, 96, 128)  0           cropping2d_8[0][0]               
                                                                 block9_expanding_conv_up[0][0]   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block9_expanding_conv_a (Conv2D (None, 96, 96, 64)   73792       concatenate_8[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block9_expanding_conv_b (Conv2D (None, 96, 96, 64)   36928       block9_expanding_conv_a[0][0]    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_18 (BatchNo (None, 96, 96, 64)   256         block9_expanding_conv_b[0][0]    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
class_output (Conv2D)           (None, 96, 96, 4)    260         batch_normalization_18[0][0]     
==================================================================================================
Total params: 31,039,620
Trainable params: 31,035,780
Non-trainable params: 3,840
__________________________________________________________________________________________________

Total params: 31,031,940
Trainable params: 31,031,940
Non-trainable params: 0
```

class percentages in dataset:

```
{0: 0.6245757457188198,
 1: 0.16082110268729075,
 2: 0.1188858904157366,
 3: 0.09571726117815291}
```

- class `0` is the background
- shape of image from generator (rgb): `(1, 96, 96, 3)`
- shape of labels from generator: `(1, 96, 96, 4)`

Comment: How did you get around the class imbalance since `class_weights` doesn't seem to work on keras?

Comment: @Jonathan, I ended up using https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/6261

Comment: Thanks for directing to me that post. Just to confirm, you used the weighted_cross_entropy right? How did you pass in the class weights and how were they computed? Did you just use the class_weights function as suggested in that forum also? It would actually be really helpful for this post if you provided your solution to solving it. i.e. your loss function and the modifications needed to pass it into compile.

Answer (score 2):

There doesn't seem to be anything that wrong in your model.

Softmax is ok, as it defaults to the last axis, and you're clearly using `'channels_last'` as config. So it's ok.

Suggestions are:

- Add a few `BatchNormalization()` layers and decrease your learning rate (this prevents relu from going too fast to "all zeroes").
- Check that your output data range is correct, with `np.unique(y_train)` containing only 0 and 1
- Check that every pixel is classified with only one class: `(np.sum(y_train, axis=-1) == 1).all() == True`.
- Check if your images aren't too biased towards the first class. `np.sum(y_train[:,:,:,0])` should not be too bigger than `np.sum(y_train[:,:,:,1:])`.

  - If it is, consider fitting with the `class_weight` parameter, passing weights to balance the loss for each class (check keras documentation on `fit` for how to use it)

Comment: What's a good learning rate? I've tried 1e-5. The class percentages are 62%, 16%, 12%, 10%. I tried using [jaccard](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-contrib/blob/master/keras_contrib/losses/jaccard.py) as my loss. Is it supposed to fix class balance issues? `np.unique(labels)` is `array([0, 1], dtype=int8)`. `np.unique(data)` is 1004 different values from 4 to 254 as float32. I also tried subtracting the mean (`(123.68, 116.779, 103.939)`), as well as other standardizations, none of which helped. I had issues with using [class_weight](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/3653)

Comment: `(np.sum(labels, axis=-1) == 1).all() == True` returns True

Comment: If you use class weights, use `{0: 100/62., 1: 100/16., 2: 100/12., 3: 100/10.}` and some of the standard keras losses (your jaccard may be collapsing some dimensions that keras will be using for applying the weights). Categorical crossentropy seems a nice one. Try the `BatchNormalization()` layers, one per block should be a good idea.

Comment: Okay I'll try BatchNormalization. When I tried using class weights I got: `'class_weight' not supported for 3+ dimensional targets.` I'm using a `fit_generator`.

Comment: Argh...  :( -- Well... just make sure that your training accuracy is better than 62%.

Answer (score 0):

**This model works just fine for me with most of the segmentation projects, i use crossentropy for multiclass segmentation and smooth dice for binary classes**

```
def conv_block(tensor, nfilters, size=3, padding='same', initializer="he_normal"):
    x = Conv2D(filters=nfilters, kernel_size=(size, size), padding=padding, kernel_initializer=initializer)(tensor)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Activation("relu")(x)
    x = Conv2D(filters=nfilters, kernel_size=(size, size), padding=padding, kernel_initializer=initializer)(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Activation("relu")(x)
    return x


def deconv_block(tensor, residual, nfilters, size=3, padding='same', strides=(2, 2)):
    y = Conv2DTranspose(nfilters, kernel_size=(size, size), strides=strides, padding=padding)(tensor)
    y = concatenate([y, residual], axis=3)
    y = conv_block(y, nfilters)
    return y


def Unet(img_height, img_width, nclasses=3, filters=64):
# down
    input_layer = Input(shape=(img_height, img_width, 3), name='image_input')
    conv1 = conv_block(input_layer, nfilters=filters)
    conv1_out = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv1)
    conv2 = conv_block(conv1_out, nfilters=filters*2)
    conv2_out = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv2)
    conv3 = conv_block(conv2_out, nfilters=filters*4)
    conv3_out = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv3)
    conv4 = conv_block(conv3_out, nfilters=filters*8)
    conv4_out = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv4)
    conv4_out = Dropout(0.5)(conv4_out)
    conv5 = conv_block(conv4_out, nfilters=filters*16)
    conv5 = Dropout(0.5)(conv5)
# up
    deconv6 = deconv_block(conv5, residual=conv4, nfilters=filters*8)
    deconv6 = Dropout(0.5)(deconv6)
    deconv7 = deconv_block(deconv6, residual=conv3, nfilters=filters*4)
    deconv7 = Dropout(0.5)(deconv7) 
    deconv8 = deconv_block(deconv7, residual=conv2, nfilters=filters*2)
    deconv9 = deconv_block(deconv8, residual=conv1, nfilters=filters)
# output
    output_layer = Conv2D(filters=nclasses, kernel_size=(1, 1))(deconv9)
    output_layer = BatchNormalization()(output_layer)
    output_layer = Activation('softmax')(output_layer)

    model = Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=output_layer, name='Unet')
    return model
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, the problem is related to model architecture. When you are dealing with a complicated dataset for segmentation, you need to enhance the model architecture. I encountered the same problem with a new dataset while the model could work well on another dataset. So, I used Res-Unet instead of Unet as the model architecture and the problem solved.
hope this will help